# Wiping: does the following function overwrites memory on android?

Tags: java, android

I wrote the following function and I would like someone to enlighten me on what happens with memory here.

```
public boolean wipe(){
    RandomAccessFile wiper = null;
    int length;
    File file;
    file = new File(fileDirectory);
    byte[] bytes = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
    length = (int) file.length();
    try {
        wiper = new RandomAccessFile(fileDirectory, "rw");
        wiper.seek(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < length/16; i++) {
            wiper.write(bytes); //~2,7MB/s on my phone (16Bytes per iteration)
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (wiper != null)
                wiper.close();
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
    }
    Boolean deleted = file.delete();
    if(!deleted){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Problem deleting file! Delete manually", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    editListView();
    return true;
}
```

To call the function:

```
if(!wipe())
    Toast.makeText(this, "Problem wiping! Wipe again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Basically I have a file at the directory and I find the length in bytes of that file. I then open the file again with RandomAccessFile and add 16bytes length number of times.
I used the following code to test the efficiency of the function:

```
public boolean wipe(){
    RandomAccessFile wiper = null;
    FileInputStream reader = null;
    int length;
    File file;
    file = new File(fileDirectory);
    byte[] bytes = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
    length = (int) file.length();
    System.out.println(length);
    try {
        wiper = new RandomAccessFile(fileDirectory, "rw");
        wiper.seek(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < length/16; i++) {
            wiper.write(bytes);
        }
        byte nextByte[] = new byte[16];
        reader = new FileInputStream(fileDirectory);
        while(reader.read(nextByte) != -1){
            System.out.print(nextByte[0]);
            System.out.print(nextByte[1]);
            System.out.print(nextByte[2]);
            System.out.print(nextByte[3]);
            System.out.print(nextByte[4]);
            System.out.print(nextByte[5]);
            System.out.print(nextByte[6]);
            System.out.print(nextByte[7]);
            System.out.print(nextByte[8]);
            System.out.print(nextByte[9]);
            System.out.print(nextByte[10]);
            System.out.print(nextByte[11]);
            System.out.print(nextByte[12]);
            System.out.print(nextByte[13]);
            System.out.print(nextByte[14]);
            System.out.print(nextByte[15]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (wiper != null)
                wiper.close();
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This code won't erase the file at the directory so it is possible to see that the file will maintain the same size in kB. And it will print all bytes present in the file after wipe in packs of 16. With this test function you can see that overwriting works and that the file is composed of 0s. The question remains as to wiping since it is not clear if memory is overpassed in this process. I'm pretty sure that most of these operations are happening in RAM but I don't think the android system will erase memory on persistent storage during the process. It would cost unnecessary operations. If this is true, it would mean that the adress of the file remain the same so if I overwrite the file with a file of the same size composed of 0s it would "wipe" it completely.
I would like to know what you think about the memory system and if this function works for wiping (securely erasing the data). If you want to test it yourself I use the directory "/storage/emulated/0/PathToAFile".

Comment: you cannot wipe a file like that. RAM barely is the issue, but the file-system is... which does not guarantee to write at exactly the same location. even if you end up with a file, which has the same name and has random content; previous data will only be un-linked. Java might be a tad too high-level for such an operation.

Comment: What kind of language could be used for this kind of thing. With the file system why would the blocks of memory change when the file is loaded/unloaded from the RAM. Even with C++ you cannot really access persistent memory directly. It would mean that you'd need to use OS specific API?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the file with append, won't it write to the end of the file? I think you need to use RandomAccessFile and seek to the start of the file before writing all zeros.

Comment: I did erase the file completely before appending the 0s but I think your solution is probably best. Even then, the question remains as to if the memory is overpassed by the new file composed of 0s. I admit your solution has more chance of working since in mine I erase the file with a FileOutputStream and then close it so it will probably write the changes back on memory at that time.

Comment: I did edit the question with RandomAccessFile and it works but the question about memory remains.